# error: void value not ignored - in simple c program

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I'm new to programming in c. When running the below code, I am getting the following error with a little arrow pointing at the = sign:

error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

*gcd = gcd_lcm((factor1 % factor2), factor2, gcd, lcm);

I tried to follow the steps in returning a value to a void type as found in another post, but does not seem to work in my code. Can someone help point out my mistake? Would much appreciate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gcd_lcm(int factor1, int factor2, int *gcd, int *lcm);

int main(void) 
{

   int factor1;
   int factor2;
   int GCD;
   int LCM;

   printf("Enter Factor1: ");
   scanf(" %d", &factor1);

   printf("Enter Factor2: ");
   scanf(" %d", &factor2);

   gcd_lcm(factor1, factor2, &GCD, &LCM);
   printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d. The LCM is %d\n", factor1, factor2, 
   GCD, LCM);

return 0;
}

void gcd_lcm(int factor1, int factor2, int *gcd, int *lcm)
{

if (factor2 == 0)
{
  *gcd = factor1;
  *lcm = (factor1 * factor2) / *gcd;
}
else
{
  *gcd = gcd_lcm((factor1 % factor2), factor2, gcd, lcm);
  *lcm = (factor1 * factor2) / *gcd;
}
}
```

I have changed the code to this and now works, but how?

```
void gcd_lcm(int factor1, int factor2, int *gcd, int *lcm)
{

if (factor2 == 0)
{
   *gcd = factor1;
   *lcm = (factor1 * factor2) / *gcd;
}
else
{
   gcd_lcm(factor2, (factor1 % factor2), gcd, lcm);
   *lcm = (factor1 * factor2) / *gcd;
}
}
```

Comment: Just remove `*gcd = `.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages some styles are more appropriate than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
void gcd_lcm(int factor1, int factor2, int *gcd, int *lcm);
```

This means that `gcd_lcm` has no return value.

Here  you are trying to use its return value (which it doesn't have):

```
*gcd = gcd_lcm((factor1 % factor2), factor2, gcd, lcm);
```

At a guess, since `gcd` is passed down into the recursive call, you can just use:

```
gcd_lcm((factor1 % factor2), factor2, gcd, lcm);
```

But if I'm not mistaken, `factor2` never changes and so the recursion will never stop...

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
*gcd = gcd_lcm((factor1 % factor2), factor2, gcd, lcm);
```

The `gcd_lcm()` function has no return value but you try to catch it.